# How to export vectors from QGIS to MapInfo?

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, vector, export, format

I am trying to save some vector lines that I made in QGIS (1.8 Lisboa) to a format that can be added to MapInfo Professional 6.0 (ancient version I know..).

When I save the vector to a Mapinfo format it produces two files: .MIF & .MIDI.

However in the Mapinfo if appears as though a vector file has 5 separate files: 
.ID .IND .MAP .MIF .DBF......and sometimes a .MIDI file.

Can I not add the vector line without these other files? If so is there any way that I can produce them? Thanks!

Comment: For clarity, MapInfo TAB format (.tab, .dat, .map, .id) is the native MapInfo vector format, whereas MapInfo Interchange Format (.mid, .mif) is, as the name suggests, an interchange format, entirely ASCII based that makes the vector data more accessible to other software. Both formats are based on multiple files, but it is not necessary to have both MIF and TAB formats to use the data in MapInfo. If you are working in MapInfo, then TAB format would be the one to choose.

Answer (score 5):

Two options here:

1) When you do Save As in QGIS right click menu, add .tab to the export filename and it will save as a TAB file.

2) In MapInfo, Import the MID/MIF using the menu options:

Table > Import.

You can then choose the MID/MIF to import and then choose a place to save the TAB file.

Comment: Does this export all the symbology applied in QGIS so that it displays the same way in MapInfo?

Comment: I haven't used MapInfo in a while but I believe it doesn't export the symbology from QGIS.